# Maximum and Minimum value of $xy$ and $xy^{-1}$

Tags: calculus

> If $(x-3)^2+(y-3)^2=1$. Then find maximum and minimum of $xy$ and $xy^{-1}$

My Try: put $x-3=\cos \theta$ and $y-3=\sin \theta$

Put $x=3+\cos \theta$ and $y=3+\sin \theta$

$\displaystyle xy=(3+\cos \theta)((3+\sin \theta)=9+3(\sin \theta+\cos \theta)+\frac{\sin 2\theta}{2}\in\bigg[9-3\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{2},9+3\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2}\bigg].$

And $\displaystyle \frac{x}{y}=\frac{3+\cos \theta}{3+\sin \theta}.$

Could some help me to solve it. I have seems that there must be an Geometric way. Please explain . Thanks

Comment: If you want a geometric approach, the level lines of $xy^{-1}$ are lines $y=Kx$ passing through the origin, and $(x-3)^2+(y-3)^2=1$ is a circle. So, you are looking for the maximum and minimum (reciprocals of the) slopes of the lines passing through the origin that intersect the circle. That will occur for the tangents to the circle passing through the origin.

Comment: observe that the domain where you have to find the maximum is the circunference of radius 1 centered in $(3,3)$. The function $xy$ grows when $x$ grows or $y$ grows. Remaining on the circunference you will reach the maximum (for simmetricity in $x$ and $y$) when $x=y$, so at the $\pi/4$ angle. That is the point $x=y=\sqrt 2/2 +3$.

Comment: @tommycautero That an optimization problem is symmetric on its variables doesn't imply that its extrema are going to be located at the points where these are equal, only that its extrema form a set symmetric with respect to $y=x$.

Comment: of course you are right, i omitted some steps, but i didnt mean that it was a direct implication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\cos\theta+\sin\theta=t\implies-\sqrt2\le t\le\sqrt2,t^2=1+\sin2\theta$

$$xy=9+3t+\dfrac{t^2-1}2=\dfrac{17+(t+3)^2-9}2$$

Now $-\sqrt2+3\le3+t\le3+\sqrt2$

$\implies(3-\sqrt2)^2\le(3+t)^2\le(3+\sqrt2)^2$

For $\dfrac xy,$  use [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) to form a quadratic equation in  $\tan\dfrac\theta2$ which is real, so the discriminant must be $\ge0$

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150994/prove-that-0-le-frac1-cos-theta2-sin-theta-le-frac43-for-all-rea/2151234#2151234